# how to get image path of highest vote

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

My table schema is as follows:

```
id  || image1   ||  image2  || image1vote  || image2vote || uid
1      abc.jpb      adc.jpg        50            40          12
2      bc.jpb       dc.jpg         20            70          13
3      kjc.jpb      ydc.jpg        20            10          10
4      pjc.jpb      mkc.jpg        80            60          10
```

I am using MySQL with phpMyAdmin as my  back-end.

From the front-end I am uploading two images which I am storing in the database. For both images I am saving the votes separately. The votes for `image1` are stored in the column `image1vote`, while the votes for `image2` are stored in column `image2vote`.

My problem is the following: I want the image path of the image that has the most votes. So, if image1 has more votes than image2, I want the value of `image1` and the other way around.

For example: In the first row, I want the value of `image1` since the value in `image1vote` is bigger than the value in `image2vote`. In the second row, I want the value of `image2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but if I understood your question correctly, it should be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  IF(image1vote >= image2vote, image1, image2) AS path,
  GREATEST(image1vote, image2vote) as votes
FROM imagetable
```

Comment: if i want highest vote also then what should i chnage in this query?

Answer (score 1):

If both images and their votes are in same table you can use case to retireve

```
SELECT 
id  ,
(CASE WHEN image1vote > image2vote THEN image1   
WHEN image1vote < image2vote THEN image2
WHEN image1vote = image2vote THEN image1 
END ) AS `images`,
(CASE WHEN image1vote > image2vote THEN image1vote  
WHEN image1vote < image2vote THEN image2vote 
WHEN image1vote = image2vote THEN image1vote   
END ) AS `votes`
,uid
 FROM `table`
```

Comment: it will return id? but i want either image1 or image2

Comment: See my query again `id` will have image id `votes` will have the votes based on comparision  `images` will have either image1 or image2 based on compassion if both image's vote are equal then image1 will be returned